# warning: left-hand/right-hand operand of comma has no effect

Tags: c++, g++

I have these warnings and I don't know how to solve them.

```
warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect
```

Code:

```
size_t cCsvAlias::operator [] (const char* name) const
{
    NAME2INDEX_MAP::const_iterator itr(m_Name2Index.find(Lower(name)));
    if (itr == m_Name2Index.end())
    {
        LogToFile(NULL, "cannot find suitable conversion for %s", name);
        Assert(false && "cannot find suitable conversion");
        return 0;
    }

    return itr->second;
}
```

Warnings comes from:

```
LogToFile(NULL, "cannot find suitable conversion for %s", name);
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
#define LogToFile (void)(0);
```

Comment: What is the definition of `LogToFile`?

Comment: `LogToFile` probably don't take 3 parameters. Show it's signature

Comment: Is `LogToFile` a macro? By convention, you should make macros all capital letters and use underscores to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: @sp2danny It's probably a macro. If it were a function, the compiler would complain about wrong number of arguments, it wouldn't turn them into the comma operator.

Comment: @Barmar are you asking about this: #define LogToFile (void)(0); ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking about. Put that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Expand the macro manually, as the preprocessor would do for you, and you get:

```
(void) (0);(NULL, "cannot find suitable conversion for %s", name);
```

The expression in the right set of parentheses consists of three statements separated by the comma operator. The compiler is warning you that the first two have no effect.

The comma operator stitches together multiple expressions, evaluating them in order. The comma-separated expression in the right set of parentheses evaluates to the value of the final expression in the chain of commas (`name` in this case). The first two expressions, however, (`NULL` and `"cannot find suitable conversion for "%s"`), don't actually do anything; this is what the compiler is warning you about.

Comment: To be precise, the `0` is parenthesised in the macro definition, so will also be parenthesised in the expansion. Also, this answer could be better if you would also give a macro definition that does not suffer from this problem. (And the obvious, `#define LogToFile(a,b,c) (void)(0)`, would cause the arguments to no longer be evaluated, so if you go that route, a warning would be appropriate.)

Comment: @hvd: Thanks, I fixed the typo above. I didn't suggest an alternative implementation because it's not clear what the OP is trying to actually accomplish. I suppose you could do something like `#define LogToFile(a, b, c) ((void) a, (void) b, (void) c)`, perhaps. This would allow the arguments to still be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks @hvd , now i don't receive these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the warning by replacing the macro with:

```
inline void __throw_to_dev_null(const void*, const char*, ... ) {}
#define LogToFile __throw_to_dev_null
```